# How to embed html in link text using Phoenix Framework?

Tags: phoenix-framework

I have a snippet that looks like this:

```
<%= link "<i class='fa fa-sign-out' aria-hidden='true'></i>", 
    to: auth_path(@conn, :delete), 
    method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
```

It is a [link](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Link.html).  I would like to put a i element inside the text, so it shows an icon instead of text.  However this escapes all the html characters and displays as text.

How do I make the i appear as html?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Put the inner html in a `do` block:

```
<%= link to: auth_path(@conn, :delete), 
    method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger" do %>
  <i class='fa fa-sign-out' aria-hidden='true'></i>
<% end %>
```

This is documented [here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Link.html#link/2).

Comment: thx Dogbert, I couldn't figure out how to convert the doc syntax to the template syntax

Comment: any reference to the `auth_path` function used? I just couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: got it. `route` functions